# Why signature diverse with same additon signed of SignedExtension?

Tags: polkadot-js, signed-extensions

I have a same call with same era,nonce,tip, and a same signer. the SignedPayload is construct by call and Extra(era,nonce,tip here), so the payload should be unchanged. but in polkadot.js I checked the signature in two trying is different.
[image]

this is two diffrent encoded result:
[image]

My questionn is are there any other factor decide the signature beside signer,call and SignedExtrension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sr25519 the signatures are non-deterministic. That means for the same input it will generate different signatures each time it is called.

This is different from ed25519 and secp256k1 where the same data always yields the same signature.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why is that? I am not knowledgeable in cryptographic procedures.

Comment: @Purple_Turtle, I am not a pro, but I am inclined to think that it won't fit to a comment and would probably be better off as a subject for another question.